# Fill recyclerview with centered items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app, I have a horizontal recyclerview with LinearLayoutManager. The recyclerview is surrounded by Relative layout whose width is match_parent. I fetch data from an API and populate the recyclerview. If the API response returns a single data item, I need to show that item in the center of recyclerview. If the API response returns two items, I need to divide the space of the recyclerview equally for the two items. If the API response returns more than two items, the items should have equal gap between each other. Please refer the below screenshot:[image]

I tried with item decoration and custom layout managers, but no use. Suggest a better solution.

Comment: by default keep a single item and then in your code check how many items you're getting and add textviews with gravity one. you'll be able to achieve the desired result

Comment: what did you close it for? this question is legit and not "too broad". he's just asking a possible implementation not any tweaks on existing code

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `gravity` as `center` and the `width` as `match_parent`. This will make the items stick to the center, whereas if multiple items are present, it will make the items spread from center. To keep the clickable area equal, you can use `LinearLayoutManager` as the Layout Manager for the recyclerView.

`LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

For the items used in recyclerView, you can keep width as `0dp` and make the `layout_weight` as `1`. So here, all items get equal weights and help you achieve your objective. Do let me know if this works.

Comment: Its not working as expected.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of how it looks with your code? So I can get a better understanding and can identify the gap.